Stuck simulating URDF robot using Gazebo (ROS 2 Humble)
I'm trying to simulate a robot in Gazebo in ROS2 Humble, but am encountering some issues. Here is the output from when I try to run the launch file:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/kwasi/.ros/log/2024-05-01-02-48-07-229933-kwasi-Compaq-CQ58-Notebook-PC-3668
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : mower.urdf
[INFO] [gazebo-1]: process started with pid [3669]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [3671]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [3673]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [3675]
[INFO] [bcd_node-5]: process started with pid [3677]
[robot_state_publisher-2] [WARN] [1714546089.558308668] [robot_state_publisher]: No robot_description parameter, but command-line argument available. Assuming argument is name of URDF file. This backwards compatibility fallback will be removed in the future.
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1714546090.841230138] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1714546090.844254921] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 3675, exit code -4, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -topic /robot_description -entity cam_bot --ros-args -r __node:=urdf_spawner']

My launch file is as follows:
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

def generate_launch_description():

use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='false')
urdf_file_name = 'mower.urdf'

print("urdf_file_name : {}".format(urdf_file_name))

urdf = os.path.join(
get_package_share_directory('mower_sim'),
urdf_file_name)

return LaunchDescription([

DeclareLaunchArgument(
'use_sim_time',
default_value='false',
description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

ExecuteProcess(
cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
output='screen'),

Node(
package='robot_state_publisher',
executable='robot_state_publisher',
name='robot_state_publisher',
output='screen',
parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
arguments=[urdf]),

Node(
package='joint_state_publisher',
executable='joint_state_publisher',
name='joint_state_publisher',
output='screen',
parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
arguments=[urdf]),

Node(
package='gazebo_ros',
executable='spawn_entity.py',
name='urdf_spawner',
output='screen',
arguments=["-topic", "/robot_description", "-entity", "cam_bot"]
),

Node(
package='mower_sim',
executable='bcd_node',
name='bcd_node',
output='screen'
)
])

